# "Relative plausibility" of some infinitary theories

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, computability-theory, forcing

*We work in $\mathsf{ZFC+V=L}$.*

---

Define a **plausible theory** to be a theory $T\subseteq\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$ in an $\omega_1$-finite language which is $\omega_1$-c.e. and $\omega_1$-finitely satisfiable; [that is](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Higher-Recursion-Theory/toc/pl/1235422631), $T$ is a theory in a countable language which is $\Sigma_1$-definable over $L_{\omega_1}$ (with parameters) and every countable subtheory of $T$ is satisfiable.

Since $L_{\omega_1}$ is uncountable, [Barwise compactness](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X0870689X) does not apply and plausible theories need **not** be satisfiable. That said, every plausible theory is "generically" satisfiable: they all become satisfiable after forcing with $\mathit{Col}(\omega,\omega_1)$, since in the generic extension we can apply Barwise compactness.

I'm interested in measuring the difficulty of "satisfiabilizing" a plausible theory via forcing. Specifically, set $T_0\trianglelefteq T_1$ iff $T_0$ is satisfiable in every generic extension in which $T_1$ is satisfiable. *(Note that by absoluteness of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-semantics we don't have to worry about theories becoming unsatisfiable.)* As usual, this preorder induces an equivalence relation $\approx$ and a corresponding poset $\mathcal{Plaus}$ of **plausibility degrees**.

I'm generally interested in the "shape" of $\mathcal{Plaus}$, but in particular the following question seems particularly natural:

> **Question.** Does $\mathcal{Plaus}$ have *coatoms*?

(See below for a proof that $\mathcal{Plaus}$ does have a top element.) I strongly suspect that the answer is negative, but I don't see how to prove that.

---

Very briefly, here's what I already know. $\mathcal{Plaus}$ is a bounded lattice: ${\bf 0}$ = "already satisfiable," ${\bf 1}$ = "requires $\omega_1^L<\omega_1$," $S\sqcup T$ = "disjoint union of models," and $S\sqcap T=\{\sigma\vee\tau:\sigma\in S,\tau\in T\}$. In fact $\mathcal{Plaus}$ is countably complete, by the obvious extensions of those operations. Moreover, ${\bf 0}$ is not the meet of countably many nonzero elements (observed by Farmer S.), and has a unique atom *(there is a plausible theory which becomes satisfiable exactly when we add a non-constructible subset of $\omega_1^L$, which has to happen when any unsatisfiable plausible theory is made satisfiable)*. Finally, $\mathcal{Plaus}$ is not linear and has $\omega_1$-many degrees; these facts follow from some easy-but-tedious forcing arguments, whose details I'm happy to add if anyone's interested. I believe these same arguments can be used to show that ${\bf 1}$ is not a nontrivial finite join (and so $\mathcal{Plaus}$ has at most one coatom), but that's a bit messier.

Unfortunately, none of this seems particularly relevant to the coatom question (except the existence of $\mathbf 1$ which is needed to pose it in the first place).

Comment: Separately it's worth noting that making an originally-unsatisfiable theory become satisfiable is really the only impact forcing can have here: by absoluteness of $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-satisfaction we can never make a satisfiable theory unsatisfiable, and by downward Lowenheim-Skolem for individual $\mathcal{L}_{\omega_1,\omega}$-sentences + Mostowski absoluteness we can never make an unsatisfiable countable theory satisfiable.

Comment: Furthermore, $\Sigma_1(L_{\omega_1})$-ness is absolute in both directions, so the set of plausible theories doesn't change when we force. This means that each generic extension $L[G]$ yields a corresponding quotient of $\mathcal{Plaus}$ where we replace "generic extension of $L$" by "generic extension of $L[G]$." "Forcing quotients" of $\mathcal{Plaus}$ might be a useful thing to think about along the way to an answer to the specific question above. But this is all just guesswork.

Comment: I always get nervous about links that don't announce their target, since Elsevier likes to shuffle their organisation.  "[Barwise compactness](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0049237X0870689X)" points to the eponymous chapter, namely [Chapter 9](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0049-237X(08)70689-X), of [Model theory for infinitary logic](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/studies-in-logic-and-the-foundations-of-mathematics/vol/62/suppl/C), edited by Keisler.

Comment: What does "sufficiently (Sacks) generic" mean?

Comment: @FarmerS Meeting some "large" but still countable set of dense subsets for the relevant forcing. E.g. the notions of $n$-generic (for Cohen forcing) in computability theory. A lot of the time we don't need full set-theoretic genericity.